# Google Sheets working with Filter but the order change when sort the sorted range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a range of data on one sheet and I want to reference this range to another sheet so that I can work on these data but on a separate sheet, Like in the next screenshots:

[This is the original Data Range][image: 1]

[This is the data using the filter function on another sheet and I added comments to them][image: 2]

So far this works okay but if I sorted the original data range, the comments will not be linked to the correct data, like in the screenshots below:

[Here I sorted the original range from Z-A][image: 3]

[You can see that the comments didn't follow the correct range][image: 4]

I realize that maybe using the filter function isn't the best way to do this but I couldn't find another way to duplicate the range on multiple sheets

[Here is a link to an example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pJmZPO83cvE24Nj_eZEwPAp-4ZKFQ04dy6EL0qzAgp0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: @Tanaike OP wants `N14` in ``C2`` and `A1` in `C15` , just like in image 2.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. I think that when the original range is sorted, it is required to know it at the destination sheet. For example, when the original range is manually sorted, OnChange trigger might be able to be used (But, as `OTHER`). But, in this case, it is required to know the initial values corresponding to the source and destination sheet. From this situation, I thought that more information might help users think of a solution or a workaround.

Comment: thanks for your reply, what workaround do you suggest?